# Populate a column in SQL with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

This is my first post, so appologies if the formatting isn't right.

I'm creating a dataset for a pie chart and for each row, i need to add a colour (COL_COL) and and colour highlight (COL_HIG) from the colour table which looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_COL](
    [COL_SEQ] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [COL_COL] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [COL_HIG] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [COL_NAM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [COL_DEL] [bit] NOT NULL,
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[T_COL]           ([COL_COL]
           ,[COL_HIG]
           ,[COL_NAM]
           ,[COL_DEL])
     VALUES
           ('#F7464A', '#FF5A5E','Red', 0), 
           ('#46BFBD', '#5AD3D1','Green', 0), 
           ('#FDB45C', '#FFC870','Yellow', 0), 
           ('#949FB1', '#A8B3C5','Grey', 0), 
           ('#4D5360', '#616774','Dark Grey', 0)
```

The SQL to generate my data from the audit table is ...

```
select count(*) as 'Visits', 
    datename(mm, AUD_DAT) as 'Month',
    'Unique Visits by Month' as 'Title',
    datepart(mm, AUD_DAT) as 'MonthNo',
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datename(mm, AUD_DAT)) AS 'rownum',
     null as 'colour',
     null as 'ColHightlight'
     into #temp
    from dbo.T_AUD
    where AUD_TYP_SEQ = 3 and datepart(year, AUD_DAT) = @year
    group by datename(mm, AUD_DAT),datepart(mm, AUD_DAT)
    order by datepart(mm, AUD_DAT)
```

The above query returns 8 rows and there are five colours in the colour table. I'm trying to get to a point where row 1-5 contains colour 1-5, then row 6 will contain colour 1, 7 contains colour 2 and so on. Rather than hard coding the number of colours, i'd like to use the count of the colours table as the count will change when colours are added to that table.

I tried using the row_number function but that just increments a number for each row and i'm not sure if i can reset that to 1 when it gets to the count of the colours table.

Could you please help me acheive this? Any help appreciated. 
Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this. `ctecolors` will mark rows with `rn(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`.
`teaud` will mark `rn(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1....)`. Then a simple join on `rn`.

```
;with ctecolors as
(select *, -1+row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn from [dbo].[T_COL]),

cteaud as
(   select count(*) as 'Visits', 
    datename(mm, AUD_DAT) as 'Month',
    'Unique Visits by Month' as 'Title',
    datepart(mm, AUD_DAT) as 'MonthNo',
      (-1+ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datename(mm, AUD_DAT))) % 5 AS rn
    from dbo.T_AUD
    where AUD_TYP_SEQ = 3 and datepart(year, AUD_DAT) = @year
    group by datename(mm, AUD_DAT),datepart(mm, AUD_DAT))

Select Visits,Month,Title,MonthNo, ctecolors.* into #temp
from ctecolors cc
join cteaud ca on cc.rn = ca.rn
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i get the following error and am not sure how to solve it. _"Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'rn' in table '#temp' is specified more than once."_

Comment: @MrNick, It is because you are inserting into temp table and there are two columns of `rn`. Simply change select into with distinct column names. I have edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked after a couple of minor adjustments. I had to change the last two lines to this from _ctecolors
join cteaud ca on ctecolors.rn = ca.rn_ and change the hardcoded value 5 to the count of the colour table _(select count(*) from [dbo].[T_COL] c where c.COL_DEL = 0)_.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want using modulo arithmetic.  I am not clear what the tables you reference have to do with your problem (is the "colors" tables supposed to be `t_col` ?  I don't know).

The following query gives an approach for how to solve this:

```
with yourquery as (
      <your query>
     )
select y.*, c.*
from yourquery y join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as numcolors
      from colors
     ) c
     on y.rownum % c.numcolors = c.seqnum - 1;
```

Note:  you should only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use single quotes for column aliases.